# create partition for boot drive

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, system-installation

I have: 
ext4 454.6Gb(409.7Gb available)

In Which I installed

12.04(precise) 32-bit

GNOME 3.4.2

Now I want to install Windows 7 without formatting my current OS.

edit: Check comments for Images

Comment: http://oi58.tinypic.com/rsxz7p.jpg - My OS

Comment: http://www.cropmyimage.net/images/0ef2e532-5860-4285-ac48-a92c7e94bd82/Screenshot%20from%202014-05-12%2012:57:23.png  -  My Partition

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using GParted.

**Note: changing your partitions may cause data corruption, always make a backup of your important data!**

1. Make sure GParted is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gparted
   ```
2. Open GParted
3. Right click on your `ext4` partition
4. Click on `Resize/Move`
5. Enter a new size for your `NTFS` partition in the `Free space following (MiB)` field

   *1 GiB = 1024 MiB, so if you want your partition to be 200 GiB it would be 204800 MiB.*
6. Click on `Resize/Move`

   *This may take some time depending on the size.*

Now it will be available as unallocated space. You can format it as NTFS now with GParted or during the installation of Windows.

---

Windows 7 will overwrite the MBR, so it'll load Windows' bootloader instead of Ubuntu's one (GRUB). You won't be able to boot Ubuntu after you install Windows until you fix this.

1. Start Ubuntu Live (using a CD or USB drive)
2. Open a terminal
3. Install GRUB:

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```

   *Replace `/dev/sda` by your hard disk.*
4. Update GRUB:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Now restart your PC and GRUB will show again, giving you the choice to boot Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: http://www.cropmyimage.net/images/c4380af9-0e24-4871-a7a2-b76211268681/Screenshot%20from%202014-05-12%2014:09:53.png

Comment: Select the partition first. If it says it can't be resized try to unmount it. If that's not possible try it with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB drive.

Comment: it is the drive in which I have Ubuntu. So I cant Unmount it

Comment: Then do this while using a Ubuntu Live CD or USB drive. You'll also have to fix GRUB using a Ubuntu Live CD or USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Take a backup of everything you value.

The easiest method would be to add a 2nd slave hard drive for Windows, unplug your Linux one temporarily, install Windows on the 2nd hard drive, then hook it all back up.  Win7 is going to nuke the MBR and put its own in there, and Windows will not add Linux to the list for you to pick from because it's lame like that.  Once you've got both drives hooked back up after the Windows install, just boot Ubuntu and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should pick up the Windows hard drive and add it to the list.

If you just want to create a partition for Windows on your Ubuntu hard drive, you can restore grub after Windows has nuked it.  Here's two different help pages that show you how to restore Grub after it has been deleted.

1 - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

2 - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014708

Comment: I am trying this in my college machine. I dont want to remove my current OS,
Since, I dont know how to connect the internet wired connection(I dont know password and MAC address)after i install new OS

Comment: I dont have valuable data to backup. Could you elaborate how to create a 2nd slave.

Comment: I was just saying that it would be easier to have Windows on a separate hard drive by itself.  Just un-plug the Ubuntu hard drive and hook up the Windows hard drive as if it's the only one in the computer.  Install Windows normally, and after it's done you can hook up both hard drives.  Boot into Ubuntu and run "sudo update-grub".  That should force the Ubuntu bootloader to detect the Windows hard drive and add it as a boot option to grub.